# If a point $M$ is inside triangle $ABC$ (with perimeter s), $MA+MB+MC$ is in [s/2,s]

Tags: geometry, inequality

By the triangle inequality, I was able to prove the first part of the following inequality. Proving the upper bound is way harder. Can somebody help me, please? I would appreciate it very much. Thanks and stay safe.

Let D be an arbitrarily chosen point inside a triangle ABC. Let segments DA, DB and DC be x, y and z respectively. Let the circumference of the triangle be u.

Show that the following inequality must hold:

$\dfrac12\!\cdot\!u<x+y+z<u$

Comment: By circumference, did you mean the perimeter of the triangle or the circumference of the circumcircle?

Comment: I think this probably answers my question, thank you very much!